# design the flow of connecting my app to message broker

Tags: asynchronous, rabbitmq, queue, message-queue, messagebroker

I want to write an SMS bulk app. using .net core webapi app and rabbitMQ. 
now, the end user want to send a message to huge number of cellphones. 
I guess can do it using two flow. 
is it correct? has another solution? or bether solution? 
I guess the green flow is better because the user waiting is less than red flow? 
maybe you say this two flow totally wrong. and I need another solution. can any one help me!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your problem down, without getting to your selected technology first.

Question:How much traffic you are required to terminate per second

Question:How much traffic sms-api(SMS Provider) can handle per second

Question:How much traceability you need per message, is the log enough or you need a permanent storage

I believe after answering these questions you would be able to have a rough idea about the design of application